# If there are 10 routers with the same WiFi name, can I connect to a particular one of them?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I was thinking about routers and WiFi networks and a question crossed my mind.

If there is a WiFi network where all routers have the same WiFi name, most operating systems will only show one instance of the WiFi name in their WiFi list list and when I connect to it, it  will automatically choose the one with the best signal strength.

My question is, is it possible to make my operating system choose a specific one amongst all the WiFi networks? Like lets say I want to choose the one with the lowest signal, is that possible?

I was just curious about this.

Comment: Not unless you have specific hardware.

Comment: What is "my operating system" ? Windows, Linux, MacOS, ...?

Comment: @Robert that doesn't really matter in this question, now does it... Only specific hardware with specific configuration could connect to a specific AP. Regular consumer hardware won't.

Comment: @LPChip Even if it doesn't matters in this case I think it is a good idea to guide relatively new users so that they understand what to avoid to get a good and understandable question.

Comment: @Robert true, good point. :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/833905/how-can-i-connect-to-a-specific-bssid is also useful if you're running linux - and essentially what you are trying to do is connect to a BSSID not a ESSID

Comment: @LPChip Any consumer hardware absolutely can do this. Under Linux, anyway. Under Windows and macOS? Not so much.

Comment: @DanielB I stand corrected then. :) I had seen a YT video of a hacker who mentioned they got specific hardware to use his tools, so I automatically assumed it would not work with every wifi adapter. His tools did work under linux and windows though.

Comment: @LPChip For “hacking”, special hardware allowing broad access may indeed be necessary. Connecting to a specific BSSID is just business as usual for Wi-Fi drivers on all platforms. It’s usually not exposed to the user though, except on Linux.